# Comments at end of method best practice?

Tags: c#, comments

I have some code which has comments after each method saying this for example:

```
// End of contructor DbFactoryDBConnection()
```

Should a comment like this be used to indicate the end of a method or not? It was something picked up from an earlier employment where it was common place.

Comment: Personal opinion: Yuck, no. Modern IDE's have syntax and structure highlighting that caters for this. Why pollute the code with comments that add no value whatsoever?

Comment: Personal opinion: What @dash said. Only reason I can see is if the method spans more than one screen, in which case there are better things you can do to improve the situation.

Comment: Well that confirmed my suspicions. They will be removed. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel such comments are after methods which body does not fit in a single screen. I believe this is a good sign for the refactoring and splitting out such long methods to shorten ones or even extracting new entities/services/helpers. This is like C# region, sometimes it is used to hide very long code blocks and this is a sign that you have some kind of a [God Object anti-patter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object).

Answer (score 2):

No. If you want to know what the braces are closing, without scrolling, you can have [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). Which is great in many ways.

Just put your cursor on braces, and if the opening of them isn't in view - it tooltips the whole line before it.

Answer (score 2):

Usually this kind of comments are an overdocumentation hassle.
The right place where a comments should exist are at the beginning of your classes and of your methods and just before where important decisions will be taken inside your code.
If you find the need to document the end of an IF, SWITCH or METHOD then it's very probable that your code should be reexamined to be simplified.

Answer (score 1):

I think this sort of commenting is completely unnecessary, and only serves to clutter the code. Most IDE's (such as Visual Studio) have had features for highlighting the scope of a method (or whatever) for many years, so i'm not sure what value you could add you your code by doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use PowerCommands for Visual Studio it add at end of braces comment what bracer end you are at i use it and it helps a lot:)

Answer (score 0):

No, such a comment should not be used. The only reason, someone would use a comment like this is the fact that the method is **way** too long. But even than, modern IDEs show you somewhere in which method you currently are and even allows folding methods back to just the definition.
Comments like this are of no value whatsoever and simply pollute the code-base.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't belong in the source IMHO; it's too easy to get out of sync with the effective source code blocks. There are extensions that will show this info for you in Visual Studio i you thing that this is helpful.